# How to detect RayHit on part of model and not entire model

Tags: unity, raycasting

I'm building a low poly role playing Hack and Slash game. When I click it renders a sprite & character moves to that location(with RayCast).

But in this case. I don't want the click to occur on side of the bridge. Clicks should only occur in green coloured part & not in the red part. How should I fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: Have you considered simply splitting your bridge into two separate physics meshes, one on a "walkable" layer and one not?

Comment: @DMGregory how to split? Can it be done in Unity Itself? Coz I don't how to use Blender. This asset is from Asset Store

Comment: Not easily. Okay, next backup: have you considered not using the display mesh for ray picking at all, but instead laying down some simpler box colliders to approximate the walkable surface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to limit clicking on a region would be to split it into two meshes and only raycast the walkable region. However, if you cannot do that, you could make it conditional on the relative position of the raycast hit.

Since the model appears to be a uniform width (no bulge or narrowing near the center along the z axis), we can imagine a box around that area. This box would exclude the bridge edges, but would include everything walkable and everything below the walkable area. Now when you raycast after a click, only move the character to the raycast hit location only if the raycast hits the bridge *and* lands in that box.

We can check this by simply comparing the z to a minimum and maximum value. For example, if the bridge is 4 units wide in total, and each side of the bridge is 0.5 units wide, and the origin of the bridge is in its center, then you can do something like the following:

```
//I'm guessing you are raycasting kind of like this:
if (Physics.Raycast(raycastStartPosition, raycastForwardDirection, out hit) {
    //Also, you are probably checking if you raycast the right thing
    if (hit.transform == target) {
        //We need to get the hit relative to the target
        var relativeHit = target.InverseTransformPoint(hit.point);
        //now just check if the hit is within our bounding box.
        //We don't need to check x or y because that is implied, since
        //we already know we hit the target.
        if (relativeHit.z < 3.5f && relativeHit.z > -3.5f) {
            //actually move the character
        }
    }
}
```